# Rodapé não responsivo

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, layout-responsivo

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui][image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]Estou fazendo um sistema web responsivo usando alguns elementos bootstrap.
O sistema todo está responsivo exceto pelo rodapé que, além de sair da posição fixa na parte inferior da tela ainda diminui o tamanho.

Segue o código html e css do rodapé:

```html
<footer class="footer">
            <div class="container">
                <span class="text-muted" style="
                    position: absolute;
                    bottom: 0;
                    width: 120%;
                    height: 60px;
                    line-height: 60px;
                    background-color: #222222;
                    margin-left: -214px;
                    text-align: center;">
                    <font>
                        <font> Desenvolvido por ****** - *****</font>
                    </font>
                </span>
            </div>
        </footer>
```

*Obs: HTML E CSS estão juntos pra evitar dor de cabeça.*

Comment: Por que o estilo está no span e não no footer?

Comment: Foi gerado por aquele editor do google que aparece quando você pressiona ctrl+shift+i, eu só mantive.

Comment: Está assim no projeto ou apenas na pergunta? Se estiver assim no projeto tente mover esse estilo para o footer.

Comment: Comentei uma foto com o projeto.

Answer (score 1):

Bom dia Mariana, então pelo que eu entendi do seu código você quer um rodapé responsivo e fixo no final da página correto? tente colocar as propriedades de estilo: width: 100%, height: 60px, position: fixed; todas na tag footer.

Comment: Então, aparentemente tem alguma grid em baixo impedindo o rodapé de ficar em baixo.

Comment: Ele até tá fixo, mas no meio da tela.

Comment: tem a possibilidade de você colocar no codepen ou algum similar?

Comment: Vou colocar uma foto do resultado.

Answer (score 1):

Tirei o position absolute, o margin, dei um width:100% e adicionei um float left, assim ele fica responsivo em qualquer dispositivo:

```
       <footer class="footer">
            <div class="container">
                <span class="text-muted" style="
                    width: 100%;
                    height: 60px;
                    line-height: 60px;
                    background-color: #222222;
                    text-align: center;
                    float: left;
                    ">
                    <font>
                        <font> Desenvolvido por ****** - *****</font>
                    </font>
                </span>
            </div>
        </footer>
```

Comment: Ficou em cima de uma possível grid invisível. Vou colocar o código completo, talvez ajude.

Answer (score 0):

CONSEGUI RESOLVER O PROBLEMA.

```
<footer class="footer" style="
        position: fixed;
        width: 100%;
        height:60px;">
        <div class="container-flex rodape">
            <span class="text-muted" style="
                position: fixed;
                bottom: 0;
                width: 120%;
                height: 60px;
                line-height: 60px;
                background-color: #222222;
                margin-left: -214px;
                text-align: center;">
                <font>
                    <font> Desenvolvido por ****** - *******</font>
                </font>
            </span>
        </div>
    </footer>
```

Só troquei o Absolute por fixed no estilo position dentro do span.

Comment: Mas o footer devia ficar fixo na rolagem de tela ou fixo apenas no final da página?

Comment: Pior, bem lembrado. Então ignora essa resposta que tá errada. O footer deveria ficar fixo no final da página.

Comment: Vou fazer uns testes e posto a resposta pra você.

Comment: Certo, obrigada.